# Get span value with no class name using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Am stuck with this,

VBA code:

```
Set html = IE.document

Set elements = html.getElementsByClassName("dropdown dropdown-toggle editable-field-title-wrapper")

Dim count As Long
Dim erow As Long
count = 0
For Each element In elements
If element.className = "dropdown dropdown-toggle editable-field-title- wrapper" Then
erow = Sheets("Exec").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
Sheets("Exec").Cells(erow, 1) = html.getElementsByTagName("span") 
(count).innerText

count = count + 1
End If
Next element
```

HTML code:

```
<span data-link="class{:~getPriorityLabel(fieldValue) ? 'editable-field label-priority-color-' + ~getPriorityLabel(fieldValue) : 'editable-field'}" class="editable-field label-priority-color-high">
    <span class="dropdown dropdown-toggle editable-field-title-wrapper" data-toggle="dropdown">
      <script type="jsv#432^"></script><script type="jsv#814_"></script>
      <span class="editable-field-title">Priority:</span>
      <script type="jsv/814_"></script><script type="jsv/432^"></script>
      <span data-link="html{>~isUndefined(fieldValue) ? 'None' : ~capitalize(~getPriorityLabel(fieldValue))}">**High**</span>
      <span data-link="visible{:state != 'saving'}" style="display: block;">
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </span>
      <span data-link="visible{:state == 'saving'}" style="display: none;">
        <script type="jsv#815_"></script><i class="icon-spinner"></i><script type="jsv/815_"></script>
      </span>
    </span>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu priority-dropdown pull-right"><li data-link="visible{:fieldValue}" style="display: list-item;">
        <a class="editable-field-commit" data-value="-1" href="#" tabindex="0">None</a>
      </li><li>
        <a class="editable-field-commit" data-value="0.07438533240156266" href="#" tabindex="0">Low</a>
      </li><li>
        <a class="editable-field-commit" data-value="0.49243981401033865" href="#" tabindex="0">Medium</a>
      </li><li>
        <a class="editable-field-commit" data-value="0.9642772538736262" href="#" tabindex="0">High</a>
      </li></ul>
    <div class="alert alert-error editable-field-message-open-left editable-field-error-message" data-link="html{>errorMessage} visible{:errorMessage}" style="display: none;"></div>
    <div class="alert alert-info editable-field-conflict-message" data-link="html{>conflictMessage} visible{:conflictMessage}" style="display: none;"></div>
  </span>
```

Please find the **High** in my HTML code and I want that letter(High) using my Excel VBA code, please help me out.!!

Please find the **High** in my HTML code and I want that letter(High) using my Excel VBA code, please help me out.!!

Comment: Can you provide more of the html or an url?

Answer (score 1):

If you actually mean the "**High**" then you can use a CSS selector.

```
Debug.Print html.querySelector("span[data-toggle=dropdown]").innerText
```

CSS query using selector:

[image: css selector]

This applies a CSS selector of `span[data-toggle=dropdown]`, which is element(s) with `span` tag having attribute `data-toggle` with value of `dropdown`.
I have used `querySelector`, which only returns the first match, as your HTML shown only has one matching element.

If you have more than one matching element then you will need the `querySelectorAll` method, which returns a `nodeList` of matching elements, and then index into that 0-based `nodeList` using the appropriate index e.g.

```
html.querySelectorAll("span[data-toggle=dropdown]").item(0).innerText
```

You would traverse the `.Length` of the `nodeList` to get all items e.g.

```
Dim aNodeList As Object, i As Long, erow As Long, count As Long
Set aNodeList  =  html.querySelectorAll("span[data-toggle=dropdown]")
For i = 0 To aNodeList.Length -1
    erow = Sheets("Exec").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    Sheets("Exec").Cells(erow, 1)  =  aNodeList.item(i).innerText
    count = count + 1
Next i
```

Comment: here,

`Set html = IE.document

Set elements = html.getElementsByClassName("dropdown dropdown-toggle editable-field-title-wrapper")

Dim count As Long
Dim erow As Long
count = 0
For Each element In elements
If element.className = "dropdown dropdown-toggle editable-field-title- wrapper" Then
erow = Sheets("Exec").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
Sheets("Exec").Cells(erow, 1) = html.getElementsByTagName("span") 
(count).innerText

count = count + 1
End If
Next element`

Where should I placeyour code?

Comment: I have. Look at the very bottom. :-) My code replaces that. You said you wanted the text "High".  You should only need html.querySelector("span[data-toggle=dropdown]").innerText for that  if first element. Otherwise, you use the very bottom one to get all matched elements.

Comment: is the URL internal?

Comment: u mean. `Debug.Print html.querySelector("span[data-toggle=dropdown]").innerText` should be replaced `Sheets("Exec").Cells(erow, 1) = element.getElementsByTagName("span")(count).innerHTML` here?

Comment: Is there a single value to retrieve or 1? If 1 then simply say Sheets("Exec").Cells(1,1) = html.querySelector("span[data-toggle=dropdown]").innerText   . No loop. Change the row number to the required row.

Comment: If multiple values then use exactly as I have put at the very bottom where I loop aNodeList

Comment: No it is just 1 :)

Comment: and I am not getting any value if i use this `Sheets("Exec").Cells(1,1) = html.querySelector("span[data-toggle=dropdown]").innerText` or am I doing wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176792/discussion-between-iltech-and-qharr).

Answer (score 0):

**Using the traditional way.**

***Change inside for loop*** ===> 
 `html.getElementsByTagName("span")(count).innerText` **To** 
 `element.getElementsByTagName("span")(count).innerText`

```
Set html = IE.document

Set elements = html.getElementsByClassName("dropdown dropdown-toggle editable-field-title-wrapper")

Dim count As Long
Dim erow As Long
count = 0
For Each element In elements
If element.className = "dropdown dropdown-toggle editable-field-title- wrapper" Then
erow = Sheets("Exec").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
Sheets("Exec").Cells(erow, 1) = html.getElementsByTagName("span")(count).innerText '--> change here

count = count + 1
End If
Next element
```

Comment: Just getting blank cell as a result

Comment: btw am getting Object variable or with block variable not set as a error pop up if I replace the code as you mentioned in your answer

Comment: Using watch window, see whats in `element` and then `element.getElementsByTagName("span")`